# Linux USB Application using libusb

Tags: linux, usb, libusb

I am trying to write an application to read and write to a connected USB device. I am using libusb. It seems after I find the device, configuration fails. I am following the developers guide for libusb at http://libusb.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html. Which states that:

> usb_set_configuration sets the active configuration of a device. The configuration parameter is the value as specified in the descriptor field bConfigurationValue. Returns 0 on success or < 0 on error.

I demonstrate in my source (below) that I use the bConfigurationValue as the configuration parameter, but my return value from usb_set_configuration is always -1. I don't understand why?

The output:

```
[user@local workspace]$ ./application 
Device Found @ Address 005 
Vendor ID 0x018d1
Product ID 0x04e12
INFO: bConfigurationValue = 1
config status =-1
claim status =-1
alt status =-22
TX status =-1
RX status =-1 -> RX char = 0
[user@local workspace]$
```

The source:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct usb_bus *bus;
    struct usb_device *dev;
    struct usb_dev_handle *android_handle;
    int status;
    unsigned char send_data = 0x51;
    unsigned char receive_data = 0;

    usb_init();

    if ((handle = locate_device()) == 0)
    {
        printf("Error: Could not open the device\n");
        return (-1);
    }

    printf("INFO: bConfigurationValue = %d\n", config_val);
    status = usb_set_configuration(handle, config_val);
    printf("config status = %d\n", status);

    status = usb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
    printf("claim status = %d\n", status);

    open_status = usb_set_altinterface(handle, 0);
    printf("alt status = %d\n", status);

    status = usb_bulk_write(handle, 4, &send_data, 1, 500);
    printf("TX status = %d\n", status);

    usb_bulk_read(handle, 3, &receive_data, 1, 500);
    printf("RX status = %d -> RX char = %d\n", status, receive_data);

    usb_close(handle);

    return 0;
}

usb_dev_handle *locate_device(void) 
{ 
    ... 
    config_val = dev->config[myDeviceIndex].bConfigurationValue;
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

The following error codes are returned when the application is ran as root:

```
Device Found @ Address 005 
Vendor ID 0x018d1
Product ID 0x04e12
INFO: bConfigurationValue = 1
config status = -16
claim status = -16
alt status = -22
TX status = -16
RX status = -16 -> RX char = 0
```

Comment: The return value is -1 according to your printout, not 0. The call is failing.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. The return value is always -1 for failure but the documentation provides no causes for failure. So I am providing a valid device with the correct configuration value and the function is failing. Why?

Comment: No idea. Do the functions set errno? Do you have appropriate privileges to set the configuration?

Comment: Interesting idea... I ran the application as root and the error codes changed from -1 to -16. I added the output to the question.

Comment: this talks about using libusb as 'root' and 'user' http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Programming/Developing_Linux_Device_Drivers_using_Libusb_API